# AJAX returns CORS error while cross origin requests is allowed at the destination page; http protcol

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http, cors

I have a domain - let's call it `http://example.com`, and a `local` host;

I need to exchange data between the local host and the `http://example.com/chat/login.php`

The login authorization will be happening in the local host with PHP, and after login some safely-hashed data will be sent to the example.com to be used later.

So here comes CORS Policy. How can I bypass that?

The code on `http://example.com/chat/login.php`

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
    
    if(1) {
        echo 1;
    }
?>
```

I was expecting it to allow me send cross origin requests to this domain.

As it seems, it doesn't!

As I send an `AJAX` request, I receive the error below:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://example.com/chat/login.php' from origin 'http://local:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Am I doing it wrong or is it because the unsafe `http` protocol I'm using or is it anything else?

Actually, I presume, my problem lies in the code at the destination page as it returns the `CORS` Error when using `fetch` in console tab.

I'd be thankful if you could help me!

The AJAX Request is being posted as below:

```
const hashdata = {json : JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user"))['hashdata']};
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://example.com/chat/login.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json',);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(hashdata));
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(this.responseText);
}
```

Where data stored in the session storage is JSON

Comment: The access headers should be placed in `http://local:8080`? That still leaves the certificate problem.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm making the request from `http://local:8080` to `http://example.com`!

Comment: I thought that `http://example.com/chat/login.php` initiated a call to `http://local:8080` which then should return hashed data?

Comment: The local host hashes some data and posts it to the `login.php`, and some `php` is run there and will respond a Boolean result with `echo` keyword.

Comment: OK, I didn't get that from your question, but now that I read it for a third time, I see what you mean.

Comment: It would have been useful to see the code of the actual AJAX request in your question. That would remove any ambiguity as to who calls what.

Comment: My apologies, here you go!

Comment: `I presume, my problem lies in the code at the destination page as it returns the CORS Error`...no, the browser generates the error. Php merely returns some headers. Learn how CORS works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Anyway as per the error message it is failing on the preflight OPTIONS request - I would guess that request never reaches php...probably the webserver isn't configured to process those via php code, or to return any CORS headers in response to an OPTIONS. Without knowing what webserver is in use we can't give more specific instructions, but now you know the likely problem you should be able to Google suitable instructions for your domain's webserver.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-Origin Request Headers(CORS) with PHP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cross-origin-request-headerscors-with-php-headers)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I'm afraid I couldn't solve my problem with the pages you referred. No I've a question, is it possible that the host I'm using prohibits Cross Origin and I thus I cannot allow CORS in my php script?

Comment: @ADyson my apologies, may I ask what information do you need?

Comment: `is it possible that the host I'm using prohibits Cross Origin and I thus I cannot allow CORS in my php script`...no, because CORS is actually controlled by the web browser. Your PHP (or webserver) can merely returns some HTTP headers which the browser then uses to help it decide how to enforce CORS rules for that particular request. A host can't really prohibit you from ouputting HTTP headers. And I also can't think of any sensible reason why they'd restrict the use of a security feature. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS to learn more clearly how CORS works

Comment: `may I ask what information do you need`...I didn't specifically ask for any information. I suggested that you find out what webserver you're using, and then google how to enable CORS headers to be returned for OPTIONS requests using that webserver (or how to ensure it forwards OPTIONS requests to PHP for processing, so PHP can return the necessary headers). If you don't know what webserver is being used, contact your hosting company (although if it's a Linux server then 9/10 times it will be Apache), and also contact them if you don't have access to make the needed configuration changes.